# Null Pointer Exception in CodeNameone Css

Tags: codenameone

[image]I would like to apply css to my codename one application, I have downloaded cn1css-ant-task.jar from git hub and put in my lib directory and I applied css to my app, everything is working fine but after some time I got an error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHWZS.png)